# c# linq group by fortnight or x number of days?

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Hi I'm trying to work out how would you group items into the first and 2nd half of each month for a given year and month?

i.e.

Say for example I have to list the name of item on the 6th of every month and the 15th of every month.

say for example I have

```
Flight Name           Flight Date

Flight 1               01/07/2012

Flight 2               12/07/2012

Flight 3               18/07/2012

Flight 4               28/07/2012
```

how would i split it up so I'd like to group flights by fortnights within a year/month

i.e

Flights For July week 1 and 2 - 2012

Flights for July week 3 and 4 - 2012

so this is what I have so far..
eventually it'll have to be some kind of view model using automapper etc i am not sure as of yet how it'd get that neatly into some kind of ViewModel form...

```
var flightEntities = from f in flightsAsViewModels
                             select new
                             {
                                YearGroups = from flightYearGroup in context.Flights
                                group flightYearGroup by flightYearGroup.FlightDateTime.Year
                                into yearGroup
                                orderby yearGroup.Key descending
                                select new
                                {
                                     Year = yearGroup.Key,
                                     MonthGroups = from flightMonthGroup in yearGroup
                                                   group flightMonthGroup by flightMonthGroup.FlightDateTime.Month
                                                   into monthGroup
                                                   orderby monthGroup.Key ascending
                                                   select new {
                                                       Month = monthGroup.Key, 
                                                       HalfMonthGroups = from months in monthGroup
                                                                         group months by (months.FlightDateTime.Day <= 15 ? 1 : 2) into splitMonthFlights
                                                                         orderby splitMonthFlights.Key
                                                                         select new { WhichHalfOfMonth = splitMonthFlights.Key, Flights = splitMonthFlights }
                                                  } 

                                 }
                            };
```

Comment: What about week 5? Nearly every month has more than 4 weeks worth of days.

Comment: Is this in LINQ to SQL (etc) or LINQ to Objects? (LINQ to Objects would make it a lot easier...)

Comment: @JonSkeet: According to the tags it is LINQ to SQL

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Bi-monthly is every two months. A fortnight is 14 days. But I think you want periods of 1-15 and 16-lastday of each month. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Hi Gert yes that is correct thank you basically the periods that are 1-15 and 16 to last day of the month is perfect thank you.. and yes linq to sql and eventually represented in a viewmodel

Comment: and the other thing will be trying to group them in to ViewModels to lay them out!!

Answer (score 0):

I hereby pasted Linq code for the requirement. But not sure, this still can be achievable in shortest way. Please let me know if so.

```
 var monthGroupedDates = from d in dates
                            group d by d.Month into fd
                            select new { Month = fd.Key, Dates = fd };

        foreach (var g in monthGroupedDates)
        {
            var groupByHalf = from n in g.Dates
                              group n by (n.Day <= 15 ? 1 : 2) into gd
                              orderby gd.Key 
                              select new { WhichHalf = gd.Key, Dates = gd };
            foreach (var gh in groupByHalf)
            {
                string printString = (gh.WhichHalf == 1 ? "First" : "Second") + " week dates are:";
                foreach (var h in gh.Dates)
                {
                    printString += h.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + ";";
                }
                Console.WriteLine(printString);
            }

        }
```

Please note, dates are one which is mentioned in your requirement. If its Linq with SQL, this may need slight alterations.

Raj